# Creating view between 2 tables allowing 1 table to be updated dynamically and the other to insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Sql Server I have two tables

```
SELECT FROM dbo.INSERT CROSS JOIN dbo.DYNAMIC
```

I want dbo.INSERT to be able to insert data while keeping insync with dbo.DYNAMIC.

While dbo.DYNAMIC can be updated at anytime with new information

Comment: Do you want create sql view?

Comment: As posted your question doesn't make any sense. The query you posted would seem to be what you need? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/